# SQL query - address referenced 2 different ways

Tags: sql, count, subquery, inner-join

If the address data was stored as shown below, what is the best way to do a query to check if a user belongs in a particular country? There is a lot of other conditions needed, so I've provided this format for simplicity.

Is doing a `union` the most efficient way in this situation?

***Tables***

**User**

```
| id |name|primaryaddrid (FK to Address id)|
|----|----|--------------------------------|
|1   |bill|1                               |
```

**UserAddresses**

```
|id|userid|addrid   |
|--|------|---------|
|1 |1     |2        |
|2 |1     |3        |
```

**Address**

```
|id|addrline1|country|
|--|---------|-------|
|1 |1 main st|usa    |
|2 |1 main st|italy  |
|3 |1 main st|peru   |
```

Answer (score 0):

> do a query to check how many users are in usa

You can count how many distinct `userid` in the `useraddresses` table have (at least) an address in the US with `count(distinct)` and a correlated subquery:

```
select count(distinct userid) as cnt
from useraddresses ua
where exists (select 1 from address a where a.id = ua.addrid and a.country = 'usa')
```

Comment: What about the `primaryaddrid` field linking directly to the `address` table? Edit: I should add, this is _not_ my database design.